# how to compare content of multiple files in windows

Tags: compare

How can I compare the content of multiple files in Windows?

Comment: The compare-and-swap tag is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below command for your requirement.

```
FC /B pathname1 pathname2
```

/B performs a binary comparison.

for more information check this http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html